# Split string value in a MultIndex level to create a new level

Tags: python, pandas

I want to split a level (of str values) in a MultiIndex using a delim to create a new level in the MultiIndex.

My original DataFrame

```py
pd.DataFrame(
    np.ones((5, 4)),
    columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
        zip(
            list(reduce(lambda x, y: f"{x}_{y}", tup) for tup in zip(range(4), range(4))),
            list(map(str, range(4))),
        )
    ),
    index=range(5),
)
```

|  | ('0_0', '0') | ('1_1', '1') | ('2_2', '2') | ('3_3', '3') |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

how can I split the 0th level with '_' delim so that I can get 3 levels in my MultIndex column efficiently? Like this

|  | (0, 0, 0) | (1, 1, 1) | (2, 2, 2) | (3, 3, 3) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

> Do not know how I can have multiple headers in markdown table. the length of the tuple suggests the levels. This is the output of `pd.DataFrame.to_markdown`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
              [[int(s) for level in col for s in level.split('_')]
                for col in df.columns]
              )
```

Output:

```
     0    1    2    3
     0    1    2    3
     0    1    2    3
0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
1  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
2  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
3  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
4  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
```

Or, for tuples:

```
df.columns =[tuple([int(s) for level in col for s in level.split('_')])
             for col in df.columns]
```

Output:

```
   (0, 0, 0)  (1, 1, 1)  (2, 2, 2)  (3, 3, 3)
0        1.0        1.0        1.0        1.0
1        1.0        1.0        1.0        1.0
2        1.0        1.0        1.0        1.0
3        1.0        1.0        1.0        1.0
4        1.0        1.0        1.0        1.0
```

Comment: damn so simple I can't believe I missed it. Love it!